# Unable to show spinner in Angular on routing request

Tags: angular, spinner, loader

I'm trying to set up a spinner to show for requests in angular 5.  So far, I've been using the tutorial found here:

https://www.amadousall.com/angular-routing-how-to-display-a-loading-indicator-when-navigating-between-routes/

It seems very straight forward; set a boolean to evaluate to either true or false depending on the event.  The only change I really needed to make for my code was to ngx-spinner in the html instead of mat-progress-bar.  However, so far I've been unable to make the spinner show up.

Here is the code for reference, though it is pretty much identical to the link's:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
import {Event, NavigationCancel, NavigationEnd, NavigationError, NavigationStart, Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    loading = false;

    constructor(private router: Router, private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) {
        this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
            console.log('Event Occured');
            switch (true) {
                case event instanceof NavigationStart: {
                    this.loading = true;
                    console.log(this.loading);
                    break;
                }
                case event instanceof NavigationEnd:
                case event instanceof NavigationError:
                case event instanceof NavigationCancel: {
                    this.loading = false;
                    console.log(this.loading);
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /*ngOnInit() {
        /!** spinner starts on init *!/
        this.spinner.show();

        setTimeout(() => {
            /!** spinner ends after 5 seconds *!/
            this.spinner.hide();
        }, 5000);
    }
*/

}
```

And here is the app.component.html:

```
<ngx-spinner [hidden]="loading==false"
             bdColor = "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8)"
             size = "default"
             color = "#ffee00"
             type = "pacman"
>
<app-nav></app-nav>
<router-outlet [hidden]="loading==true">
</router-outlet>
```

What I would like is for the spinner to show while `loading` is true, and for the `router-outlet`, and the content it provides, to be hidden.  Once `loading` is false, the spinner will be hidden and the content will be shown.

So far, I've only been able to get the spinner to show when I comment out all the cases except for NavigationStart, preventing `loading` from ever changing to false.  In addition, I was able to see the content returned by router-outlet behind the spinner, despite the hidden tag on it.  I was able to get it to hide by placing it in a div:

```
<div [hidden]="loading==true">
    <app-nav></app-nav>
    <router-outlet>
    </router-outlet>
</div>
```

But that still doesn't solve the fact that when I allow `loading` to evaluate to false, I never see the spinner in the first place; it instantly loads the components returned by router-outlet.  I'm a beginner at angular, so this is running me up the wall.  Is this simply a case of the loading going to fast for me to see the spinner, or is something else at play?

Comment: please create a stackbliz

Comment: I couldn't replicate your problem. it's working for me

Comment: Do you have this in your code?  `getTeams(): Observable<string[]> {
    return of(['Barcelona', 'Real Madrid', 'Toulouse', 'PSG']).pipe(delay(2000));
  }` it's in the tutorial github repo

Comment: try https://github.com/kKen94/ngx-progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't see the spinner because it hides very fast. Attach some resolver to routing to see spinner in action. Your spinner is probably visible for about 100ms.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a timeout here to force the spinner to show

```
case event instanceof NavigationCancel: {
  console.log(this.loading);
  // force to wait 2 seconds to see the spinner.
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.loading = false;
  }, 2000);
  break;
}
```

As Karol mentioned, it happens too fast to see the spinner otherwise. Which is okay, you do not wait for something from a remote server. This all happens quite fast locally.

Comment: Of course it‘s not. It is here an example to force the wanted behavior.

Comment: Please make this a comment since it's not an answer